# Member voice state return value problem in discordpy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For a simple example, I prepared the following code. Although there is no missing permission of the bot, when I query it using "fetch_member" it return None, I don't know how to fix this problem please help.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    a = await client.fetch_guild(ctx.guild.id)
    
    b = await a.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)
    
    print(b.voice) #return value is None
    
    print(ctx.author.voice) #return value is VoiceStateObject
```

Comment: Why are you using `fetch_member` instead of just `ctx.author`?

Comment: I can't use ctx because i make rest api for bot

Comment: Did you give your bot the correct [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)?

Comment: No i did not add intents to bot

Comment: Look at enabling the [members intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go).

Comment: I will try this

Comment: The result is still the same

Comment: The interesting thing is that it just returns the audio value as none

Comment: this is usual since you fetched the guild. fetching the guild does not return all the info

Comment: Even [the docs mention this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild)

Comment: So what can i do

Comment: just use `ctx.author.voice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not discord.py specific issue as the data is just not provided by the Discord API. To avoid this just use `ctx.author.voice` or use get_guild instead of fetch_guild

Here's a screenshot of the docs for [Guild.fetch_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild): [image: docs]

Comment: I didn't think to look at the documentation. After reviewing what you wrote, I found a method. Thanks

guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
guild._voice_states[member_id]

Comment: yeah `get_guild` does give that info, the docs for `fetch_guild` also suggest using `get_guild`. although the `_voice_states[member_id]` should just be `.get_member(member_id).voice`

Comment: Looking at the source code for member.voice, [it uses `guild._voice_states_for`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/member.py#L606-L609) which in turn uses [guild._voice_states`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/guild.py#L301-L302) that you are using. so what you have is essentially the same as member.voice